# HNN embedding theorem for countable groups not preserving amenability

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

The well-known embedding theorem for countable groups by Higman-Neumann-Neumann says that

> ***Theorem 1:*** Every countable group can be embedded in a 2-generated group.

One can prove this theorem using wreath product (instead of HNN-extensions) in order to preserve solvability, see [Embedding Theorems for groups, Neumann-Neumann 1959](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s1-34.4.465)

I know that with a similar but not identical construction one can obtain an analogous result for amenable countable groups:

> ***Theorem 2:*** Every amenable countable group embeds in a 2-generated amenable group.

See [HNN Embedding Theorem for Amenable Groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30653/hnn-embedding-theorem-for-amenable-groups)

My question is the following: Is there a countable amenable group $G$ such that the Neumann-Neumann construction (theorem 1) fails to preserve amenability?

Comment: The NN construction is not theorem 1. It is some precise construction (using unrestricted wreath products) in a given paper, which is used to prove theorem 1. You precisely refer to this very construction. It might be hard to answer your question without a summary of this construction. (Also, I think this question would better fit MathOF)